# Gaussian width vs. Gaussian complexity

Tags: probability-theory

Source: Vershynin High Dimensional Probability page 181 Exercise 7.6.9

Consider the subset $T\subset \mathbb R^n$. Its Gaussian complexity is defined to be
$\gamma(T):=\mathbb{E}\sup_{x\in T} \left\vert \big<g, x\big> \right \vert $ and its Gaussian width is $w(T):=\mathbb{E}\sup_{x\in T} \big<g, x\big>$, where $g\sim N(0,I_n)$ is a standard Gaussian vector.

The goal is to establish the following inequality:

For any set $T\subset \mathbb R^n$ and a point $y\in T$, we have

$$\frac{1}{3}[w(T)+\|y\|_2]\le \gamma(T) \le 2[w(T)+\|y\|_2].$$

I know the following equality may be helpful (follows from his proposition 7.5.2(e)):

$$w(T)=\frac{1}{2}w(T-T)=\frac{1}{2}\gamma(T-T).$$

So the problem boils down to finding the relations between $\gamma(T-T),\gamma(T)$, the points in $T$ that are farthest and nearest to the origin. But I don't know how to give a desired description (it's okay to replace the constants $\frac{1}{3}$ and $2$ with other constants).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upper bound:

Writing $x = x-y+y$ and using the triangle inequality, we have
$$E \sup_{x \in T} |\langle g, x \rangle | \le E \sup_{x \in T} | \langle g, x-y \rangle| + E| \langle g, y \rangle |.$$
<s>The second term equals $\|y\|$.</s> The first term is bounded by $\gamma(T-T) = 2 w(T)$.

Correction: the second term is $E|\langle g, y \rangle | = \|y\| E_{Z \sim N(0,1)}|Z| = \sqrt{2/\pi} \|y\| \le \|y\|$. Thanks to yxc for pointing this out.

Comment: thanks! do you know how to deal with the lower bound?

Comment: @EditPiAf Thanks for the ping

Answer (score 2):

The lower bound:

$3E \sup_{x\in T}|\langle g,x\rangle|\ge E \sup_{x\in T}|\langle g,x\rangle|+2 \mathbb{E}|\langle g,y\rangle|\ge w(T)+2\sqrt{2/\pi}\|y\|\ge w(T)+\|y\|$

Answer (score 0):

This meant to be a comment, but I can't seem to do so.

Regarding angryavian's answer, the second term does NOT equal $\|y\|$. It is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\|y\|$, which is bounded above by $\|y\|$. For more information, one can refer to Eg. https://www.quora.com/If-Y-X-where-X-has-normal-distribution-N-0-1-what-is-the-density-function-expectation-and-variance-of-Y

One should also find $\mathbb{E}|\langle g,y\rangle|=\|y\|$ intuitively bothering: having this equality would mean that for $X=\langle g,y\rangle$, we have $ (\mathbb{E}|X|)^2=\mathbb{E}(X^2)$ and $$
\text{Var} |X|=\mathbb{E}(|X|^2)-(\mathbb{E}|X|)^2=\mathbb{E}(X^2)-\mathbb{E}(X^2)=0,
$$ which implies $|X|$ is constant with probability 1, and we know that this is not necessarily true.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error.